# Solr not returning all indexed documents

Tags: solr, oracle12c

I have encountered problem that Solr is not returning all indexed documents.
After completing full-import than going to web UI's Schema Browser there is correct information about document count, but when querying for all, there are ~400 documents missing. Following 2 pictures show Schema Browser and Query views
[image: Schema browser view]

---

[image: Query view]

Loading Term Info also shows all documents and even those which are not shown  with queries. After click on term the query is made that return nothing.

Database ID's are unique and can not possibly overlap.

Here's code fragment from data-config

```xml
<entity name="PZ" pk="DOKUMENTA_ID" transformer="TemplateTransformer, ClobTransformer"
        query="
SELECT pz.dokumenta_id,
        ... // selecting other non pk fields
    ">
            <field column="primaryKey" template="${PZ.DOKUMENTA_ID}" />
            <field column="DOKUMENTA_ID" name="pz_id" />
    ...
```

primaryKey is defined in schema.xml as unique key

Comment: try this PZ_id:*:*

Comment: Is core in "current" state?

Comment: Hello, sorry, my bad, another table's primary key values were overlapping with this table's already indexed values, so in the end those keys were overwritten.